# How to transfer data between native webview and react js page?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, webview, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing a `PWA` application combined with android native using `Android-studio` by using `webView`.
I have a `webView` and pages load on it , But i need to send some information from device (using my native application) to react-Js page.

I've tried to set header for `webView` but it seems that headers can't read directly in react-Js app.

Anybody know how can i send and receive data between `webView` and react-Js app?